# Turn Signal Randomly Changes Directions

Tags: electrical, lights, turn-signal

I have a 2005 Dodge Dakota. The left turn signal has started randomly switching over to blinking the right signal light. When it happens, the sequence is usually:

- Turn on the left signal, it blinks for a couple of times
- An out of sequence and slightly more quiet click is heard and the right signal begins flashing

Turning the signal off and then back on again gets the left signal going again.

I have confirmed that it is the entire right signal lights (not just the dash indicator). Also, all of the bulbs are working properly when the left signal is in fact flashing.

I have not had the reverse situation happen with the right signal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds most likely to be a fault in the switch in the indicator stalk - normally you have a physical linkage which keeps the turn indicator flashing while you turn a corner, then it releases as the steering wheel straightens.

I can imagine a couple of ways this could fail and allow the spring in that mechanical return to perhaps trigger the right signal. Realistically, this will mean a replacement of the indicator switching components.

Have you checked it in a straight line and on corners to see if it is linked with steering wheel position?

Comment: I have noticed that the degree of tilt in the steering wheel does affect it. I usually drive with the wheel tilted full down, but one day I ended up one click from there and I noticed the signal worked properly the whole drive.